# Can haml render <input type="text" required>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, haml

Haml can render

```
%input{:type=>"text"}
```

as

```
<input type="text">
```

Wonder what it should be in haml so it's rendered in html as

```
<input type="text" required>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't really if this is the correct way, but I always do `required: true` for that kind of attributes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the [value of an attribute is a boolean](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#boolean_attributes), e.g.

```haml
%input{:type=>"text", :required => true}
```

it will be rendered as either

```
<input required type='text'>
```

if the [`format` option](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/Haml/Options.html#format-instance_method) is `:html4` or `:html5`, or as

```
<input required='required' type='text' />
```

if the format is `:xhtml`.

If the value is false, it will be omitted altogether:

```
<input type='text' />
```

Answer (score 2):

`%input{type: "text", required: true}/`

or

`%input{:required => "", :type => "text"}/`

Source: http://www.htmltohaml.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
%input{:required => "", :type => "text"}/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
%input(type="text" required=true)
```

[html style attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#htmlstyle_attributes_)